# Why can't I use the ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor engine (with the new @-syntax) in a UserControl?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a `UserControl` that will read data from an XML file and populate a `ListBox`.  I've open up the `.ascx` file and would like to use `@foreach (etc..)` but this isn't valid?

Can someone explain why this isn't possible?  Or maybe confirm if `UserControl`s are deprecated in MVC 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ascx` is WebForms. `@` is Razor, meaning that if you want to write `@foreach(...)` you need a Razor template: `Foo.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.Foo>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    ...
}
```

And if you want WebForms user control `Foo.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<AppName.Models.Foo>>" 
%>
<% foreach(var item in Model) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: So, in general, using a `UserControl` in MVC 3 isn't a good idea?

Comment: @Ardman, server side controls are not a good idea. As far as the view engine is concerned you could perfectly fine use WebForms or Razor or both in ASP.NET MVC 3. So you could use WebForms usercontrol but make sure that it inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`. As far as the Razor view engine is concerned there is really no distinction between views partials (aspx vs ascx).

Comment: So the control's event is triggered as well? Even it is render on other page, which will go and fire up the control's OnLoad, ButtonClicked event as well?